# Group Like Records in SSRS Report for Data Driven Subscription

Tags: reporting-services, subscription, data-driven

Working on a report in SSRS that will be sent to multiple users but each user should only get their own records.  In my main dataset I have a field for the distribution that I could use for grouping but I'm not exactly sure how to get it to work in a subscription.  I've used the Data Driven one before but only for a single user and only so the report is sent when data exists, I've never done one with a dynamic distribution.

I tried using the main query for the data driven source but it ended up creating one e-mail per record so I ended up with 40 e-mails, all with the same attachment.

Comment: You should write your query so there is only one line per user. If your dataset has 50 rows, you need to do a distinct select for the user on that data set.  It would help if you show a sample of your dataset to give you a targeted answer

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure how much adding the code itself will help as the code runs fine I'm just trying to find out if there is a way to link the report output to the data driven subscription data set.  As for one record per user are you talking about the data driven data set or the report data set? The report itself will have to have more than one record per user as it's tracking orders and it's a one to many relationship.

Comment: I'm talking about the dataset for the data driven subscription. I'm not talking about showing your code... that's just hte bot. but show sample data if  you want more help..